# Convert working form data in POST request to Postman request

Tags: html, forms, post, request

I have a working example that sends a request with a HTML form.

```
<html>
    <form action="{{url}}?id=123" method="POST">
        <input name="request_token[key]" id="key" />
        <button type="submit">go</button>
    </form>
</html>
```

I want to send the same request with Postman, but I don't know how to set the parmeters.
I tried to add "key" with the value in the body in json format (Content-Type was set to application/json). It did not work. And many other variations either.

```
{
    "key": "{{theKey}}"
}
```

In the network tab, chrome sends `request_token[key]` as key name. This could not be the one I should send?

How do I convert this example to a working postman request?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution^^

The key name is "request_token[key]". I was irritated cause I get an error if I want to add brackets in the header. But if I add this key as form-data and not in json format, it works.